# Read sheet music trouble

Tags: piano, sheet-music, self-learning

I'm new. I got some trouble when read this song, I don't know Bm(b5) meaning. Also some word "Bb" "Dm",... I know it suggestion note make from chord in treble & bass clef. But sometime it lack a note from chord or note in one line can't make a chord as suggestion. Help me, please.[image]

Comment: All YOU, as a keyboard player, have to do is play the printed notes.  The chord symbols are a description of the harmonies they contain.  They might be of use to e.g. a guitarist accompanying the piece.  (Be aware that sometimes chord symbols provide a functional harmonic analysis, sometimes they're just utilitarian, indicating what notes to play.  Sometimes they're not a COMPLETE description of what's going on.  Don't waste time analyzing something like the Bm(b5) too closely.  Just note that B, D and F are required.

Comment: "Loss of Me" is a popular mistranslation of this piece's title, but the generally accepted translation of the title nowadays is "Rose of May". (The katakana for the last word of the title matches "May" much better than "me".) It's from Final Fantasy IX. (This video game also has some other doubtful translations for its music titles, such as "Sword of Doubt"/"The Wavering Blade" and "Something to Protect"/"Protecting My Devotion".)

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I, as a keyboard player, will find those chord symbols (if accurate..!) very useful to change voicing or extemporise later on in songs, instead of playing the same old all through. Probably easier than trying to translate what the harmonies are (supposed to be) from the dots.

Comment: If you extemporise, why keep to the original chords? (Also - why was this question closed?  We demonstrably have more to offer.  And it ISN'T the same question as the one cited.  That was about a piece that WASN'T fully notated.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know Bm(b5) meaning

That would be a B minor with  a flat fifth, that is add the seventh (A) and lower the fifth (from F# to F). So the notes become B, D, F, A.

> I know it suggestion note make from chord in treble & bass clef. But sometime it lack a note from chord or note in one line can't make a chord as suggestion

Those are not for the person playing the parts on the staff, those are for someone accompanying the player (for example a guitar). Or if you want to improvise, so you know what chords you're supposed to improvise on.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Bmb5 is rarely played as such, and you're right, there's usually a '7' included - Bm7b5. However, that 7 is the melody note here. It also gets called Dm6, and would be better as that in the key of that song, maybe?

Comment: @Tim given the other Dm chords around it, yeah, that would probably make sense. But I guess they used Bm(b5) because of the chord voicing?